# remove "empty" elements from multidimensional array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a multidimensional array something like this

```
[ [[]], [[1], [2]], [[1, 2]] ]
```

What's the best way to remove the empty array?

Right now I am just doing a `array[1..-1]` to remove the first element but I would like a more reliable way to do it.

Comment: What do you want to do with `[ [[],[1]], [[1],[2]] ]`?

Comment: @muistooshort note that your array is different from mine. i'll be comparing it against other arrays to find the shortest substring. i'm getting this by doing something like `ar.each_index.map{ |i| ar.combination(i).to_a`

Comment: So you're saying that you can't get `[[],[1]]` as an element? I'm just trying to clarify what your data really looks like.

Comment: @muistooshort yep, can't get [[], [1]]. but you can get [ [[]], [[1], [2]] ] for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flatten each array and if it has no elements in it, delete it.

```
arr = [ [[]], [[1], [2]], [[1, 2]] ]
arr = arr.delete_if { |elem| elem.flatten.empty? }
# => [[[1], [2]], [[1, 2]]]
```